# I have error for install electron on fedora 30

Tags: node.js, electron, fedora

Hello i have this error if i try to install electron on my fedora 30

```
[luisjustin@localhost ~]$ sudo su
[sudo] password for luisjustin: 
[root@localhost luisjustin]# npm install -g electron
/usr/bin/electron -> /usr/lib/node_modules/electron/cli.js

> electron@5.0.2 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/electron
> node install.js

/usr/lib/node_modules/electron/install.js:49
  throw err
  ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/electron/.electron'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron@5.0.2 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@5.0.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-05-30T01_21_04_805Z-debug.log
[root@localhost luisjustin]#
```

the log in this link: https://pastebin.com/q3dSCQVg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with permissions on your machine (`/usr/lib` directory requires root access). What I suggest you to try is to change the default directory where `NPM` is installing packages globally. Then you can try to run the installation without root access.

Try this:

1. On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

   `mkdir ~/.npm-global`
2. Configure npm to use the new directory path:

   `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`
3. In your preferred text editor, open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

   `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`
4. On the command line, update your system variables:

   `source ~/.profile`
5. To test your new configuration, install a package globally without using sudo:

   `npm install -g electron`

Courtesy:
https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally